# Can't pass variable into function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a list of dataframes and I can't figure out why I can't define conc and t0 outside of the function.

If I do it like this I get error:

> 'Error in nls.multstart::nls_multstart(y ~ fit_drx_mono(assoc_time,
> t0,  :    There must be as many parameter starting bounds as there are
> parameters'

```
conc <- 5e-9
t0 <- 127

nls.multstart::nls_multstart(y ~ fit_mono(assoc_time, t0, conc, kon, koff, ampon, ampoff),
                             data = data_to_fit,
                             iter = 100,
                             start_lower = c(kon = 1e4, koff = 0.00001, ampon = 0.05, ampoff = 0),
                             start_upper = c(kon = 1e7, koff = 0.5, ampon = 0.6, ampoff = 0.5),
                             lower = c(kon = 0, koff = 0, ampon = 0, ampoff = 0))
```

When I specify the values in the function everything works as it is supposed to. And I don't understand why.

Comment: Not applying/working with `{nls.multstart}`. However, googling for the error brought up an interesting discussion: https://github.com/padpadpadpad/nls.multstart/issues/13. It feels like the problem described there following the initial response is comparable to your situation. The page also provides options to deal with this issue. Pick the one that is most interesting for you. The moment you pass a variable holding the value, you break the expectation of the function re variable names/values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't find that discussion googling myself.
It turned out I cannot define `data = data_to_fit` otherwise the function looks for variables only in that dataframe. Once I defined every variable outside of the function without specifying `data` it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I cannot define `data = data_to_fit` otherwise the function looks for variables only in that dataframe. Once I defined every variable outside of the function without specifying `data` it works.